# Для чего нужно INTO

Tags: mysql, sql

Сегодня, разбираясь в коде одного сайта, который мне нужно подправить, обнаружил запрос вида `INSERT table ....` сразу в глаза бросилось отсутствие `INTO`, полез в [офф. мануал](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html), да, таки не обязательный параметр, но все в той же [офф документации](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) я не нашел для чего оно используется. Еще в детском саду меня приучили писать

```
INSERT INTO table
```

Но просто из любопытства, может кто знает зачем оно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Затем же, зачем AS и прочие слова, облегчающие восприятие.
Insert into table звучит благозвучнее и правильнее, чем insert table.

Comment: Вероятно, Вы правы. Глянул стандарт, там INTO как обязательный параметр стоит. По всей видимости, в MySQL решили что чтение-чтением, но лишнее слово набирать не по фен-шую и разрешили его опускать ))

Answer (score 0):

Согласно стандарту, INTO - обязательное слово в операторе INSERT, но некоторые диалекты так не считают, в частности T-SQL. Уже не раз на этом попадался, используя сгенерированный скрипт.

Так что лучше следовать стандарту, дабы избежать лишних проблем.